# How to fix the Iteration problem for Json array in Pug

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am trying to print the json data in pug view engine in tabular form using node and express

I have tried for each loop in pug

My app.js file looks like

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
var pple = require('./product.json');
console.log(pple);
const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('product', { products: pple, title: "Product Details", message: "Products" });
});
app.listen(4000);
console.log("Listening Port : 4000");
```

and my product.pug file looks like

```html
  head
    title= title
  body
    h1= message
    br
    table(style="width:50%",border="1")
        tr
            th  Id
            th  Name
            th  Quantity
        tr(each product in products)
            td= product.id
            td= product.name
            td= product.quantity
```

and least but not last my product.json looks like

```
{
 "products": [
        {
            "id": 99,
            "name": "Nokia 7",
            "quantity": 6
        },
        {
            "id": 100,
            "name": "Iphone X",
            "quantity": 5
        },
        {
            "id": 101,
            "name": "Samsung Galaxy",
            "quantity": 7
        },
        {
            "id": 102,
            "name": "Moto G5 S+",
            "quantity": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

I am expecting that Data from product.json file should be printed in tabular format but I am getting an error  -

```
TypeError: E:\StudyBits\FullStack\Express_assignment\assignment_preILP_002\views\product.pug:13
    11|             th  Quantity

    12|         tr(each product in products)

  > 13|             td= product.id

    14|             td= product.name

    15|             td= product.quantity

Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at eval (eval at wrap (E:\StudyBits\FullStack\Express_assignment\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:40:65)
    at template (eval at wrap (E:\StudyBits\FullStack\Express_assignment\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:48:201)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (E:\StudyBits\FullStack\Express_assignment\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:427:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (E:\StudyBits\FullStack\Express_assignment\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:417:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (E:\StudyBits\FullStack\Express_assignment\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:464:11)
    at View.render (E:\StudyBits\FullStack\Express_assignment\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (E:\StudyBits\FullStack\Express_assignment\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (E:\StudyBits\FullStack\Express_assignment\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (E:\StudyBits\FullStack\Express_assignment\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at app.get (E:\StudyBits\FullStack\Express_assignment\assignment_preILP_002\app.js:9:9)
```

can anyone help me on this error.
thank in advance

Comment: `pple` may need to reference `require(./product.json).products` instead of the whole JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('product', { products: pple, title: "Product Details", message: "Products" });
});
```

use

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('product', { products: pple.products, title: "Product Details", message: "Products" });
});
```

Because you are `require("./product.json")` which itself is an `object` and not an `array`.

Or otherwise, if you do not want to change the `pple` to `pple.products` you could also change your `product.json` to:

```
[
    {
        "id": 99,
        "name": "Nokia 7",
        "quantity": 6
    },
    {
        "id": 100,
        "name": "Iphone X",
        "quantity": 5
    },
    {
        "id": 101,
        "name": "Samsung Galaxy",
        "quantity": 7
    },
    {
        "id": 102,
        "name": "Moto G5 S+",
        "quantity": 4
    }
]
```

so you get an array returned by `require("./product.json")`.

**Edit**

The above only fixed the problem, that products is not an array. You must change the template too:

```
head
    title= title
    body
        h1= message
        br
        table(style="width:50%",border="1")
            tr
                th  Id
                th  Name
                th  Quantity
            each product in products
                tr
                    td= product.id
                    td= product.name
                    td= product.quantity
```

The line `each product in products` must be on it´s own, otherwise you would add attributes to the tag ( https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html )

Comment: Sorry, did not test it before. The second problem was in the product.pug. Now I tested the code and it works. Otherwise leave another comment :-)